# Sorting alphabetically not working

Tags: python, django

I have a model that has a name field. It's defined as follows

```
name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=150, unique=True)
```

Then, when I retrieve the models, I want to sort the results in an alphabetical order. To get the first 25, I do the following:

```
Company.objects.order_by("name").defer("bic")[:25]
```

This results in a funny order:

1. Avocado Outdoors GmbH
2. Apricot Computers
3. Banana Corporation
4. Apple Computers GmbH

Why's that?

I also have the following but it shouldn't affect the ordering, should it?

```
for company in company_list.iterator():
    companies[company.id] = company
```

The list above is printed based on `companies` in the latest code snippet.

Comment: Not that it is relevant but if you are already slicing the queryset to return 25 objects, why are you using the `.iterator()`? It is only useful to avoid loading all the objects into the memory.

Comment: Perhaps try `Company.objects.defer("bic").order_by("name")[:25]` or drop the defer completely with `Company.objects.order_by("name")[:25]`.

Comment: @aus_lacy No difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I was actually getting them in the right order from the database but then I iterated them as shown earlier.

```
for company in company_list.iterator():
    companies[company.id] = company
```

I wasn't aware that dictionaries don't have order. I was thinking this like ArrayLists in Java. They stay in the order they are inserted. Later I was using this dictionary to print out the companies.

I changed the type of companies from dict to OrderedDict and it solved the problem.

So instead of having

```
companies = {}
```

I did

```
companies = OrderedDict()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in the `Django QuerySet` documentation that states:

> Note that using iterator() on a QuerySet which has already been evaluated will force it to evaluate again, repeating the query.

So if you are calling iterator then it will reevaluate the `QuerySet` which could cause a discrepancy in the ordering.

As is mentioned in the first comment, there is no need to use an iterator since you are already forming the `QuerySet` with the line

```
Company.objects.order_by("name").defer("bic")[:25]
```

Comment: This has no effect what so ever. Using Django Debug Toolbar, I grabbed the query it was performing and manually executed it on the database with SQLite Administrator. These results were sorted correctly.